# working dev environment symfony2.3

Tags: symfony

I'm working with a project symfony version 2.3.6 specifically. The problem is that I make changes in the code but the change is not reflected on the page until the page charge many times. I'm in dev environment. is as if not compile the code every time I load the page. Are not you supposed to be in dev environment should always be compiled? a greeting

Thanks four your answer. I use MAMP and php 5.5.3 and no select cache.
the app_dev is:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
//$kernel->loadClassCache();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

i comment the line  //$kernel->loadClassCache(); but the problem no solve.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's cache problem

Comment: Have you apc cache installed? If so try disabling APC

Comment: please post your web/app_dev.php file contents

Answer (score 1):

Symfony caches everything by default, especially Twig. And it's tedious, I know.

Looking at the manual (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html) it says:

> If you add a template in a new location, you may need to clear your
>   cache (php app/console cache:clear), **even if you are in debug mode**.

And so, you need to clear the cache. But attention deleting all, because the user sessions are stored in `/cache/dev/sessions`. That's another strong limitation: Symfony2 requires a writable filesystem.

There is a radical solution, but your app could get really slow, also in *dev* mode:

```
twig:
    cache: false
```

In your `config.yml`

Comment: thanks for you answer Fabio, changes in templates twig view result immediately but any change in a driver and clearing the cache rm -rf app/cache still not updating changes until after 20 sec or 30 sec

Comment: the problem is thath php 5.5.3 install opcache i disable opcache i work correctly. thanks.